# Mockito.spy with Junit5

Tags: java, junit5, spy

with spy object in Junit5 Mockito.dothrow in not giving real exception what specified in doThrow instead giving different kind of RealTimeProxy exception

```java
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.mockito.Mockito;

public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test(){
        B b = Mockito.mock(B.class);
       A a = new A(b);
       A aSpy = Mockito.spy(a);
       Mockito.doThrow(C.class).when(b).someMethod();
        Assertions.assertThrows(C.class,()->aSpy.testMethod());


    }

    public  class A{
        B b;
        public A(B b){
            this.b = b;
        }

        public void testMethod(){
            b.someMethod();
        }
    }

    public  class B{
        public void someMethod(){

        }
    }
public class C extends RuntimeException {
    }
}
```

Instead of getting Exception of type class `C` I am getting different kind of exception(`org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.mockcreation.RuntimeExceptionProxy`) and tests are getting failed.

Could some one let me know how to work spy in Junit5

Comment: i think you have wrong import `powermock` and i don't know if you are using it

Comment: @Deadpool there are no `powemock` imports

Comment: where does this come from `org.powermock.api.mockito`?

Comment: @Deadpool that is I could not understand, If I run tests on normal Object `a` instead of `aSpy` it is working fine.

Comment: can you update all imports from that class

Comment: @Deadpool I updated in the question, please check

Comment: I just ran your test against Mockito 3.0.0, and it passes. What version of Mockito are you using?